# Drop list columns from dataframe using dplyr and select_if

Tags: r, list, dplyr

Is it possible to drop all list columns from a dataframe using `dpyr` `select` similar to dropping a single column?

```
df <- tibble(
  a = LETTERS[1:5],
  b = 1:5,
  c = list('bob', 'cratchit', 'rules!','and', 'tiny tim too"')
)


df %>% 
  select_if(-is.list)
```

> Error in -is.list : invalid argument to unary operator

This seems to be a doable work around, but was wanting to know if it can be done with `select_if`.

```
df %>%
  select(-which(map(df,class) == 'list'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Negate`

```
df %>% 
  select_if(Negate(is.list))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  a         b
  <chr> <int>
1 A         1
2 B         2
3 C         3
4 D         4
5 E         5
```

There is also `purrr::negate` that would give the same result.

Comment: Thanks, that's a new function i'd never heard of.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(Negate(is.list), df)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  a         b
#  <chr> <int>
#1 A         1
#2 B         2
#3 C         3
#4 D         4
#5 E         5
```